# Extract substring from column based on values from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql, redash

In SQL (let's assume ANSI standard SQL), is it possible to extract a substring from one column, based on another table, and put this substring into another column?

Example, from the following tables:

```
VISITS
name       summary
---------------------------------------------
john       visit to London
jack       hotel in Paris with park visits
joe        b&b in Paris with ice cream
james      holidays in London and museums
jason      visit in Milan and fashion tour

LOCATIONS
id    name
-------------
1     Paris
2     London
3     Milan
4     Berlin
```

The idea is to extract the location from the `summary` column and output the following:

```
VISITS
name       summary                              location
---------------------------------------------
john       visit to London                      London
jack       hotel in Paris with park visits      Paris
joe        b&b in Paris with ice cream          Paris
james      holidays in London and museums       London
jason      visit in Milan and fashion tour      Milan
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: @GMB I usually do it but in this case I'm not sure — I'm using the Redash platform and not sure what standard they're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pattern matching:

```
select v.*, l.name
from visits v
left join locations l on v.summary like concat('%', l.name, '%')
```

As commented by jarlh ANSI sql has operator `||` for string concatenation, so, depending on your database:

```
select v.*, l.name
from visits v
left join locations l on v.summary like '%' || l.name || '%'
```

Comment: ANSI SQL way: `... '%' || l.name || '%'`.